# How to compile openssl Android.mk file with Android NDK under MacOSX?

Tags: openssl, android-ndk

Im trying to compile the open ssl project for android (https://github.com/fries/android-external-openssl).

I did download the files from git and tried to follow instructionq. I did installed the latest Android NDK.

I first installed the files in : `/Users/myname/Documents/workspace/android-external-openssl`
Then trying to compile with NDK-build i understand that I need a `jni` directory. So I did copy the project in another directory.

New path : `/Users/myname/Documents/workspace/jni`

But now when I try the following command : `/Users/myname/Documents/android-ndk-r5b/ndk-build NDK_PROJECT_PATH=/Users/myname/Documents/workspace Android.mk`

I get : "make: Nothing to be done for `Android.mk'."

The Android.mk is as follow :

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

subdirs := $(addprefix $(LOCAL_PATH)/,$(addsuffix /Android.mk, \
                crypto \
                ssl \
                apps \
        ))

include $(subdirs)

# static library
# =====================================================

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_SRC_FILES:=

LOCAL_C_INCLUDES:=

LOCAL_WHOLE_STATIC_LIBRARIES += libcrypto-static libssl-static

LOCAL_MODULE:= libopenssl-static

include $(BUILD_STATIC_LIBRARY)
```

Can someone tell me what Im doing wrong ?

Also in the README.Android they telling to do this command :
Run `./Configure linux-generic32 no-idea no-bf no-cast no-seed no-md2 -DL_ENDIAN`
   in the openssl distribution directory.

When I do this nothing happen and I get error that `./Configure` is unknown command...

Pleae HELP ! :))

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why you get the errors, 
I would suggest using [this one](https://github.com/eighthave/openssl-android) (ported for standalone NDK) which I compiled for my project,

To compiling for Android is as simple as :

```
cd openssl-android/jni 
ndk-build
```